# Format TimeSpan value in xaml

Tags: c#, string-formatting, timespan

I have code :

```
<Label Width="100">
    <Label.Content>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="CurrentTime" StringFormat="Total: HH:MM:SS"  IsAsync="True"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

But it formats the timespan to `12:14:34.3456577`.
How should I format the string to not show this part after the dot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ContentControl` like `Label` use [ContentStringFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat) with the right [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287).

```
<Label Width="100" ContentStringFormat="Total: {0:hh\:mm\:ss}">
    <Label.Content>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="CurrentTime" IsAsync="True"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```